# php header function

Tags: function, redirect, header, timing

can I use point in time?

something like:

```
header('refresh:1.5; url=xxx');
```

Comment: tried,seems work!
thanks everyone

Comment: neverless I suggest reading ["Drawbacks" and "Alternatives" on the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_refresh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use:

```
header('refresh: 2; url=someurl.php');
```

Where `3` is the time in seconds. More info about the `header` can always be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

But anyway I always advocate a combination to avoid problems with some browsers:

- Header (as you're doing)
- Meta tag (in the HTML head)
- JavaScript timeout

When using the `header` I don't think you can use a decimal like `1.5`. In any case I doubt any user notices the difference between `2` and `1.5` seconds. But if this is important to you, you can achieve it by using the JavaScript timeout.

**Redirection ways**

Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/someurl.php">
```

JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   window.location = "http://www.yourwebsite.com/someurl.php";
}, 1500);
```

Comment: I need the time between 1 and 2 second

Comment: I tested it, you can use a decimal, though I didn't time it which means that it is possible that the actual implementation converts it to an integer so it would be equivalent to 1.

Comment: No. I tested it,I set it to 1 and redirect too fast,set it 2 also too long,then I currently set it 1.75,enough time for reading message

Comment: Perfect. Then you can just use the first solution. Still take my remarks into account though.

Answer (score 0):

header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can, but before any headers already sent:
Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

If you need time between 1 and 2 second you can use 1.5 as u declared in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`refresh` is not part of the HTTP standard. It is a legacy method introduced by Netscape and implemented by other browsers as well. Even if it works on one browser you cannot be certain it will work on all browsers.

The W3C discourages the use of it, for details see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_refresh). Especially the sections "Drawbacks" and "Alternatives" are of interest.

I'd prefer to use this over `header('refresh ...')`:

```
usleep(1500000);
header("Location: xxx");
```

This will send a clean 302 redirect and make sure it's HTTP conform and works with every browser.